# Foreign key and update records

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys

I created three table: products, article and category.I joined tables for foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `added` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `nazwa` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kategoria` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sn` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `godzina` time NOT NULL,
  `warranty` date NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`nazwa`) REFERENCES `article`(`article_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`kategoria`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Everything works correctly. The problem is when I try update record in table products.

I try this:

```
    UPDATE `products` 
SET 
    `added` = 'michal',
    `nazwa` = 'ball',
    `kategoria` = 'toys',
    `sn` = '14dsa564dsa65',
    `data` = NOW(),
    `godzina` = CURTIME()

WHERE
    `id` = 13
```

but this query not working.

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`test`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`nazwa`) REFERENCES `article` (`article_id`))    0.157 sec

Look when i wont return records from the datbase I used this query:

```
SELECT 
    products.id,
    products.added,
    article.nazwa,
    category.kategoria,
    products.sn,
    products.quantity,
    products.data,
    products.godzina,
    products.warranty
FROM
    products
        LEFT JOIN
    category ON products.kategoria = category.category_id
        LEFT JOIN
    article ON products.nazwa = article.article_id
ORDER BY id
```

For update I used:

```
UPDATE `products` 
SET 
    products.added= 'michal',
    article.nazwa= 'ball',
    category.kategoria = 'toys',
    products.sn= '14dsa564dsa65',
    products.data = NOW(),
    products.godzina = CURTIME(),

LEFT JOIN
    category ON products.kategoria = category.category_id
        LEFT JOIN
    article ON products.nazwa = article.article_id
WHERE
    `id` = 13
```

but throws error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN     category ON products.kategoria =
>   category.category_id         LEFT' at line 10 0.000 sec

Comment: And do you get any error messages

Comment: Are you trying to update `nazwa` and/or `kategoria` with values that do not yet exist as `article_id in article` and/or `category_id in category` Because they are foreign keys those other rows must already exist in the other 2 tables

Comment: What are the left joins for? I'd say remove them and everything is going to work fine.

Comment: your table name is products or product ?

Comment: Previous comment relates to the fact you have used `product.` and not `products.` in those unnecessary joins

Comment: Are you trying to `UPDATE` all three tables at once? You can't do that.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to save the value `piłeczka pingpongowa` in an `INT(11)`.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` is in the wrong place, it has to be before `SET`.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry both clicked update at the same time,

Comment: Yes i wont update records in three tables. I corrected the question in the first post. Please check it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `article` table does not contain a row with a

```
article_id ='piłeczka pingpongowa'
```

and as this column is defined as an INT(11) it would not go into this column anyway.

And your `category` tables does not contain a row with

```
category.category_id = 'zabawki2'
```

This column is also defined as INT(11) in your schema! So this also will not work

You cannot create children before you create the parent!

Also remove both the `JOIN`'s they are not needed